# ssh connection refused all of a sudden

Tags: linux, ssh

I was logged into a remote server and it was working fine.
Suddenly my linux terminal stopped responding and I restarted it (while I was logged in)
Now when I try to ssh I get
ssh: connect to host my_ip my_port : Connection refused

I checked if ssh is running and it is.
It is listening on the same port too.

What can be the issue?

Comment: How did you check that SSH is still running? Do you have access to console of the server?

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici Yes I could ssh into it through one of my other servers and check it. Now the issue is gone. It was not even in fail2ban. I am baffled.

Comment: This looks like a routing issue. How many hops you have from workstation to the server?

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici how do I figure that out?

Comment: To find the number of hops (routers) on the path, run `traceroute <destination_host>` on your workstation.

Comment: It's taking 15 hops. How would that have been helpful?

Comment: Yes, it could be a network problem. And the fact that you were able to access from a different host, it probably means that it was a temporarily routing problem. Next time, run traceroute. If you see a couple of hosts more than once, you have a routing loop.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would check is IP conflict. Alternatively, a firewall issue (either external one or internal `iptables -S` or `firewall-cmd`).

The error message clearly indicates that some device actively responds with a REJECT.

Answer (score 1):

Check a `DenyUsers` directive in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
$ grep DenyUsers /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

It should be empty or shouldn't contain your user.